# PyQt5 processes MousePressEvent but not KeyPressEvent

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm not sure why the following minimal code prints the mouse but not keyboard events. As far as I can tell, both methods have been overloaded correctly in my custom widget (housed inside a main window). Any ideas?

```
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(CustomWidget(self))
        self.show()


class CustomWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        pass

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more googling I found this in the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop):

> You must enable keyboard focus for a widget if it processes keyboard events. This is normally done from the widget's constructor. For instance, the QLineEdit constructor calls setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus).

Thus, adding a focus policy using the line `self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)` fixes the issue.

The complete corrected code is as follows:

```
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(CustomWidget(self))
        self.show()


class CustomWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        pass

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    exit(app.exec_())
```